# angular ui-router reload / factory reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developping an application with several views for y sport association.
one for listing tournaments, and one for detailed view of a tournament, were ou can register.

My data comes from a factory. Whenever i tried to refresh views, using at least the refresh button of chrome/ie/etc, it works for the tournament view but not for the detailed one.

Tournament controller  :

```
baclyApp.controller('tournoisCtrl',['$scope','tournois','$cookies','$state','growl',function($scope,tournois,$cookies, $cookieStore, $window,$state,growl){
    //Liste des tournois
    $scope.tournois=tournois.list();
    console.log($scope.tournois);

    $scope.reloadRoute = function() {
    $state.reload();
    };

}]);
```

Detailed controller snippet (as it is very long, )

```
baclyApp.controller('detailtournoisCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$stateParams', 'tournois','$cookies','growl', function($scope, $state,$stateParams, tournois,$cookies,growl) {
//Detail du tournoi
        $scope.tournois=tournois.list();
        console.log("tournoi : "+$stateParams.cid); // displays cid fine
        $scope.tournoi = tournois.find($stateParams.cid);
        console.log($scope.tournois);
        $scope.selectedtournoi = explodeseries($scope.tournoi);

        // console.log($scope.selectedtournoi);
        $scope.showinscris = false;
        $scope.baclyusersdouble = tournois.list();
        $scope.baclyusersmixte = tournois.list();
        $scope.forminscris={};
        // console.log($scope.baclyusersdouble.users);
        $scope.hideparticiper=true;
```

Factory :

```
baclyApp.factory("tournois",function($http){
//Provider qui recupère les données de tournois et iscriptions
    // var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
    var urlphp="http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/";
    var tournois={};   
    $http.get(urlphp+"getTournois.php").success(function(data)
     {
         tournois.tournois = data;
     }).error(function(status) {
    alert("pas d accès réseau") 
    });
    $http.get(urlphp+"getTournoinscriptions.php").success(function(data)
     {
         tournois.inscriptions = data;
     }).error(function() {
    alert("pas d accès réseau") 
    });    
    $http.get(urlphp+"getTournoinscris.php").success(function(data)
     {
         tournois.inscris = data;
         console.log(data);
     }).error(function() {
    alert("pas d accès réseau") 
    });    
    $http.get(urlphp+"getUsers.php").success(function(data)
     {
         tournois.users = data;
     }).error(function() {
    alert("pas d accès réseau") 
    });

    return {
        list: function(){
            return tournois;
        },

        find: function(cid){
            return _.find(tournois.tournois, function(t) {return t.tournois_id === cid});
        },

        findinscris: function(cid){
            return _.filter(tournois.inscris, function(t) {return t.tournois_id === cid});
        },
        findusers: function(uid){
            return _.filter(tournois.users, function(t) {return t.user_id === uid});
        },
        findusersbyname: function(name){
            return _.filter(tournois.users, function(t) {return t.uname === name});
        },
        updateinscription: function($params){
            // var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
            var urlphp="http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/";
            var tournois={};
            var retour="retour-OK";

            $params_encoded =encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($params));  
            $http.get(urlphp+"saveinscription.php?data="+$params_encoded).success(function(data){
                // console.log("retour-OK"+data);
                retour="retour-OK";
            });
                return retour;
       },
        insertinscription: function($params){
            // var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
            var urlphp="http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/";
            var tournois={};
            var retour="retour-OK";

            $params_encoded =encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($params));  
            $http.get(urlphp+"saveinscription.php?data="+$params_encoded).success(function(data){
                console.log("retour-OK"+data);
                retour="retour-OK";
            });
                return retour;

        },
        deleteinscription: function($params){
            // var urlphp="http://localhost/cordova/mbacly/www/php/";
            var urlphp="http://bacly.fr/baclymphp/";
            var tournois={};
            var retour="retour-OK";
            $params_encoded =encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($params));  
            $http.get(urlphp+"saveinscription.php?data="+$params_encoded).success(function(data){
                console.log("retour-OK"+data);
                retour="retour-OK";
            });
                return retour;

        }                           
    }
})
```

app config : detailed states

```
.state('tournois', {
    url: "/tournois",
    views: {
        "main": {
            templateUrl: "partials/tournois.html",
            controller: 'tournoisCtrl'

        }
    }
})
.state('detailtournoi', {
    url: "/detailtournoi/:cid",
    views: {
        "main": {
            templateUrl: "partials/detailtournoi.html",
            controller: 'detailtournoisCtrl'
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'not reloading' and when it should be reloading. Things to keep in mind are: (1) in angular, services are singletons, which means that if you use the service in multiple controllers, the state of the service is preserved -- you don't get a new service instance per controller. (2) Services pull your data from an API on demand. So for example, of your service issues a GET to an API and then the data changes on the API, those changes will not automatically be reflected on your service, unless you do another GET. Please be more specific about what exactly fails.

Comment: i'll try to be more specific. When i load the tournament page, it loads the tournois factory. then i can click on an item list to see the detail component. When i try to refresh the page (using F5 for example) directly from detailed tournament page with url like /detailtournoi/80/ where 80 is the id of the tournament, i fails to load thing. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: when you say that i must do another get, how should i perform this ?